# Flutter button without Material anymore?

Tags: flutter, button

I was trying to include button without Material or Cupertino with no luck.

I used WidgetsApp as base.

Then I found this:
https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/buttons

Does it mean Button can't be included without Material or Cupertino?

If not, could somebody share example?

Answer (score -1):

For using the button you have to put `Directionality` widget on the top. Usually, this is `MaterialApp` or `CupertinoApp` but also you can use `WidgetsApp` widget or `Directionality` widget directly.

For example, you can check this simplified code

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Directionality(
      textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
      child: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(child: Text('Hello'), onPressed: () {},),
      ),
    );
  }
```

[image]

Comment: but `ElevatedButton` adds `import 'package:flutter/material.dart';` so I suppose it's the material widget?